# Удаление элемента по Id

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть обработчик который добавляет данные в listView1

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Url = "http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/news/add/?usersid=" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
        string json = RequestJson(Url);
        ResponseJson(json);
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        var Id = Convert.ToString(obj["id"]);

        string His = textBox1.Text;
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 120);
        listView1.Columns.Add("ID в бд", 120);

        ListViewItem newitem = new ListViewItem(His);
        newitem.SubItems.Add(Id);
        listView1.Items.Add(newitem);
    }
```

Есть contextMenuStrip1 который удаляет данные

```
    private void удалитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView.SelectedIndexCollection collection = listView1.SelectedIndices;
        if (collection.Count != 0)
        {
            string Url = "http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/news/del/?id=" + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(collection[0]);
            RequestJson(Url);
        }
    }
```

Но удаляет он по ListViewItem(His), как сделать что бы пкм по элементы ListViewItem(His), я при этом удаление происходило по newitem.SubItems.Add(Id); ?